# How create an exponential equation with points? (natural exponential)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, exponential-function

How do I make exponential equation with points?

Here are my points:

```
x = 0, y = 0
x = 1, y = 4.75000
x = 2, y = 9.26250
x = 3, y = 13.54937
x = 4, y = 17.62191
```

this is same as

```
x = 0, y = 0
x = 1, y = (0 + 5) * 0.95 
x = 2, y = ((5 * 0.95) + 5) * 0.95
x = 3, y = (((5 * 0.95) + 5) * 0.95 + 5)) * 0.95
x = 4, y = ((((5 * 0.95) + 5) * 0.95 + 5)) * 0.95 + 5) ) 0.95
```

as x value increase by 1, y value is added by 5 and multiplied by 0.95
i tried to make an equation for this but i couldn't

also i tried to use natural exponential but the initial value is 0 so it didn't work

please help me

Comment: It seems like you have a geometric sum going on here. Can you figure out the equation for the $n$:th term?

Comment: The second box you wrote is already pretty good; I would suggest rewriting $y$ in the form $y = 5\times (0.975 + 0.975^2 + 0.975^3 + \dots)$

Comment: No i tried but i couldn't that's what I'm trying to figure out please help me

Comment: @MattiP. no but if the x value gets bigger the equation will get bigger so i want to find the equation for the nth term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence is

$$y_{n+1}=0.95(y_n+5)$$ that you can rewrite as

$$y_{n+1}-95=0.95\,(y_n-95).$$

Then by induction,

$$y_n-95=0.95^n(y_0-95)=-95\cdot0.95^n$$ and

$$\color{green}{y_n=95(1-0.95^n)}.$$

Comment: where did you get 95 from? and how are they equal to each other?yn−95=0.95n(y0−95)(3rd line)

Comment: @HIYUM: this is elementary algebra.

Comment: could you please explain where you got 95 from please? i'm sure that it's not came from 100 - 95 nor 0.95 so how did you come up with that number?

Comment: @HIYUM From $y_{n+1} = 0.95(y_n + 5)$, we have $y_{n+1} - 0.95 \cdot 100 = 0.95(y_n + 5) - 0.95 \cdot 100$, so we get $y_{n+1} - 95 = 0.95(y_n + 5 - 100)$.

Comment: oh thank you so much could please explain about this as well?yn−95=0.95n(y0−95)

Comment: @HIYUM: what's your math level ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I"m really bad in math, i want to improve my math skill

Comment: @HIYUM: apply the recurrence several times (under my form)

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes i did it but i still don't get it shouldn't yn−95 equal to (yn+1−95)/0.95 according to line 2?

Comment: @HIYUM: line 2 doesn't say that.

Comment: could you please explain how you came up with the equation in line 3 from line 2?

Comment: @HIYUM: apply the recurrence several times (under my form).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did but i still don't get it

Comment: also if i change the recurrence yn+1=0.9(yn+5) it gives me this equation, yn=-95 * 0.9^n + 90 , but if i use that equation, i don't get the right answer

Comment: @HIYUM: what's the use of changing coefficients randomly ???

Comment: i just wanted to see if it will work if i change the coefficient. i did it in the same way as you did but the equation is not correct. could you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite this in terms of a recurrence relation: $a_n = \big(a_{n-1}+ 5 \big) \cdot 0.95$, where $a_n$ is the $n$th term.

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a(n)+%3D+(+a(n-1)+%2B+5)*0.95,+a(0)+%3D+0), the closed form with $a_0 = 0$ is $-95 \big ((0.95)^n - 1 \big)$, and graphing this on Desmos gives [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xdhtuxz5lg).

Comment: Thank you for answering to my question but i am trying to get the equation that can give me the exact y value that i mentioned in the question

Comment: @HIYUM Your first box and second box do not give the same equation. For the first box, why don't you try Lagrange interpolation such as on [here](https://www.dcode.fr/lagrange-interpolating-polynomial)?

Comment: oh sorry it's 0.95 not 0.975 i just edited. I tried the Lagrange interpolation but the equation is too long and not really related because it doesn't contain 5 or 0.95