# how to get natural exponential equation with points?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, exponential-function

Here are my points

$x = 0, y = 10000 \\ x = 1, y = 10421.716 \\ x = 2, y = 10882.302  \\ x = 3, y = 11385.341\\ x = 4, y = 11934.746 \\x = 5, y = 12534.791 \\x = 6, y = 13190.142 \\ x = 7, y = 13905.899\\ x = 8, y = 14687.628$

Here are my values.

The initial value for $y$ is $10000$.
As $x$ value increase by $1$, $y$ is multiplied by $1.8^{0.15}$ and subtracted by $500$.

How can I make natural exponential equation with these points? or is it impossible to make natural exponential equation with this?

Comment: It seems like you have a geometric sum going on here. Try to figure out the terms of the geometric series and you're on your way.

Comment: I'll start with the first terms:
$$ 10~000 = 10~000
$$
$$ 10~000\times 1.8^{0.15} - 500 = 10~421.72
$$
$$ 10~000 \left(1.8^{0.15} \right)^2 -500 \times 1.8^{0.15} - 500 = 10~882.302
$$
Can you figure out the next expression?

Comment: yes but i want to get the equation for the nth term

Comment: With my previous comment, I'm pushing you to the right direction and trying to make you understand how such an equation is made, in case you need it in the future. I'm encouraging you to do the work yourself, so that you learn. Do you know how to continue the series that I started there?

Comment: Yes i know i did that but the equation gets bigger and bigger as the x value increase so i'm trying to find the equation for nth value

Comment: You are correct that there will be more and more terms. But we know exactly how many terms. And we know what all the terms are. It's a geometric sum. Do you know how to calculate a geometric sum?

Comment: actually we don't those values are only first 8 values that's why i am trying to get equation for nth term. and no i don't know how to calculate geometric sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite the terms so that we see the pattern emerging. For brevity, I'll set $1.8^{0.15} = q$:
$$ 10~000 = 10~000 $$
$$10~000 q - 500 = 10~421.72 $$
$$ 10~000q^2 -500q^1 -500q^0 = 10~882.302$$
$$ 10~000q^3 -500q^2 -500q^1 - 500  = 11~385.34$$
$$ 10~000q^4 -500q^3 -500q^2 - 500q - 500 = 11~934.75$$
The last one we can rewrite in a bit clearer form:
$$ 10~000q^4 -500(q^3+q^2+q + 1) = 11~934.75$$
We see that, when $x$ is increased by $1$, the exponent in the first term is increased by one and another power of $q$ appears in the bracketed sum. The sum in the brackets is a geometric sum, which is equal to (proof is omitted)
$$
1 + q + q^2 + q^3 + \dots + q^{n-1} = \frac{1-q^{n}}{1-q}
$$
Plugging this result in, we get the general expression
$$ y(x) = 10~000q^{x} - 500 \frac{1-q^x}{1-q} \qquad \text{with }q=1.8^{0.15}
$$
If we want to rewrite this in terms of $e$, we can set $r = \ln{1.8^{0.15}} = 0.15\ln{1.8}$ and then
$$ 
\begin{split}
y(x) &=& 10~000e^{rx} - 500 \frac{1-e^{rx}}{1-e^r}\\
&=& 10~000\exp{(rx)} - 500 \frac{1-\exp{(rx)}}{1-\exp{(r)}}\\
\end{split}
$$

Comment: oh wow i've never thought about this thank you very much . but can you make an equation that includes e base (natural exponential) as well?

Comment: If you think that it's the correct answer, please mark it with the green check.

Comment: I'm sorry but if i subsitute x in to the first equation i don't get the right answer. i get 29231.027709037207 when the x = 1. i promise you that i will mark it with the green check if i get the right equation

Comment: I had a slight typo in the last equation, fixed it now. Now I get exactly the same values with the last equation.

Comment: I hope that you carefully study my solution and learn it, so that you know how to solve similar problems in the future.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ucvrl1hvsu

Comment: thank you so much for answering all my questions

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the sequence
\begin{align}
y_0&=a,\quad y_{n+1}=b\,y_n+c,\quad b\ne1
\\
\text{is }\quad 
y_n&=b^n\left(a+\frac{c}{b-1}\right)
-\frac{c}{b-1}
.
\end{align}

For this question you have

\begin{align}
a&=10000,\quad b=1.8^{0.15},\quad c=-500
\\
\text{and }\quad
y_n&\approx 4575.335040\cdot1.8^{0.15\,n}+5424.664960
.
\end{align}

For the other [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2751283/122782) you have

\begin{align}
a&=0,\quad b=0.95,\quad c=5\cdot0.95=4.75
\\
\text{and }\quad
y_n&= -95\cdot0.95^n+95
.
\end{align}